# Discord.js test if a user is offline

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, if-statement, discord.js

I'm working on my bot and I can't get it to respond. I am offline so I'm testing on myself.

Here is my js:

```
    if (member[message.guild.id].id.user.presence.status === "offline") {
    client.channel.get(status[message.guild.id]).send("Offline");
    }
```

When it refers to member its a json file and here is its value if this helps

```
{
  "719634604008538192": {
    "id": "638368326996983848",
    "bot": false,
    "username": "丂んﾑW刀 りの乇丂",
    "discriminator": "2435",
    "avatar":  "afbec0b7cc719ba3d103a60bf72e220e",
    "lastMessageChannelID": "719969405034954834",
    "flags": 0,
    "createdTimestamp": 1572269269466,
    "defaultAvatarURL": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/0.png",
    "tag": "丂んﾑW刀 りの乇丂#2435",
    "avatarURL": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/638368326996983848/afbec0b7cc719ba3d103a60bf72e220e.webp",
    "displayAvatarURL":
"https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/638368326996983848/afbec0b7cc719ba3d103a60bf72e220e.webp"
  }
}
```

I didn't get any errors but I think it's just the if statement not being true.

Comment: Beautify/format your code, its hard to look at. Why do you have a json file with that though, wouldn't it be better to just use discord.js responses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn’t need to store the members in a JSON file. You can just use the Discord.js API, such as [`Guild#members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=members).

To test if a user is online, use [`Presence#status`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Presence?scrollTo=status):

```js
const member = /* however you want to get the member */
// To get a member from a guild by ID, use guild.members.cache.get(id)
// To get a guild by ID, use client.guilds.cache.get(id)

if (member.presence.status === 'online') {
  // member is online; do something here
}
```